# Typescript 1.7+ How to add String prototype function?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.7

Anybody knows how to extend a base class in Typescript 1.7. Something like this example in JS:

```
String.prototype.foo = function() {
    return 'Bar';
}
```

I found many ways to do this in older versions of Typescript, like:

```
interface String {
    foo(): string;
}

String.prototype.foo= function() {
    return 'Bar';
}
```

or

```
interface StringConstructor {
    foo(): string;
}

String.foo = function() {
    return 'Bar';
}
```

I tried many ways to do this, but I aways get error while TS is compiled!

Thank you

Felipe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006955/typescript-extends-error-uncaught-typeerror-this-is-not-a-x-object/34008818?noredirect=1#comment55809786_34008818).

Comment: Are you using external modules? What's the error you get? If you are using external modules then you need to move the interface into a definition file.

Comment: You are right David.. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

The following still works [in action](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=interface%20String%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20foo()%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0AString.prototype.foo%3D%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20'Bar'%3B%0A%7D):

```
interface String {
    foo(): string;
}

String.prototype.foo= function() {
    return 'Bar';
}
```

You probably have it in an *external* module which disconnects it from the *global* context. More on this : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html

Comment: The unique trick is interface definition should be in a definition file.

Comment: It works but produces the following error: `TS2339: Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'String'` in typescript 1.8